# MYSQL: Help with a left join? Might be better as two queries?

Tags: php, mysql

Im not to versed in mysql JOINS, but I think that is what is required for what I am trying to do.

With the help of SO, I got this excellent piece of SQL for calculating a count of items in my database (by categories):

```
SELECT SUM(`tid` IS NULL) AS `total_null`,
       SUM(`tid` = 0) AS `total_zero`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT `tid`) AS `other`
  FROM `mark_list`
 WHERE `user_id` = $userid
```

Now what I need the query to do is check another table: **mark_options** to see if the value **groupthem = 1**.  If **groupthem = 1** then the above query should be used.  If **groupthem = 0** then I would like to use the following query:

```
  SELECT tid, 
         COUNT(*) AS other
    FROM mark_list 
   WHERE userid = $userid
```

Is it better to run 2 queries, the first one to check if groupthem = 1 or 0, then have PHP decide which final query to run, or to use an SQL JOIN (or other method) to do the same function in a single query?

Thanks!!

Comment: are you going to ask here for every query do you need? :P

Comment: @yes123 Sorry about that, Im just confused as to whether its better to do this as two separate queries or not.

Comment: if that's your question 99% of the time 1 query is faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plz send teh reps.  Kthx bai.

```
  SELECT SUM(`mark_list`.`tid` IS NULL) AS `total_null`,
         SUM(`mark_list`.`tid` = 0) AS `total_zero`, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT `mark_list`.`tid`) AS `other`,
         COUNT(`mark_list`.`tid`) AS `ungrouped`,
         `mark_options`.`groupthem`
    FROM `mark_list`, `mark_options`
   WHERE `mark_list`.`user_id` = $userid
GROUP BY `mark_options`.`groupthem`
```

Comment: @mootinator thanks! This seems to be working although in reverse  between groupthem = 1 or groupthem = 0  Easy fix to that?

Comment: @Mark This comment puzzles me.  The intent of the query was to provide both results and have PHP decide which columns to use.  I also assumed mark_options is a table with a single row.

Comment: @mootinator ah, maybee im using the wrong data in PHP.  Right now im adding the other, total_null and total_zero data in PHP to come up with a total sum.  The total sum is the correct count (depening on whether groupthem is = 0 or =1), its just the reverse of what it should be.  Let me try using ungrouped I guess?

Comment: @mootinator no still reversed, based on whether my database has groupthem set to be 0 or 1

Comment: The value of groupthem shouldn't affect the result. :/

Comment: @mootinator it does for sure, im doing it right now back and fourth :)

Comment: I don't think I can help any more without seeing more of what you're doing.

Comment: @mootinator Thanks for the effort man I really appreciate it anyways